# Is there a rate limiting tool for linux that can limit rates per process or socket?

Tags: linux, socket, rate-limiting

I found tc, which allows you to filter by ip, port etc. and then limit rates.
But I was wondering if there was anything that could filter by application or
limit rate given another process' socket ..

Thanks!

ok seems like

I can use lsof -iTCP and ipfw pipes ... wonder how efficient that is ..

lsof -iTCP: http://danielmiessler.com/study/lsof/

ipfw: http://www.macgeekery.com/hacks/software/traffic_shaping_in_mac_os_x

ipfw in C: http://psb.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?ipfw+4

with rate limiting (dummynet): http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-115.2/ipfw.tproj/ipfw.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netfilter (iptables) has the `owner` (and also a `socket`, if you wish to use that) module. With it you can apply standard firewall rules if user id or group id matches, and optionally match if the packet is associated with a socket.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m owner -u some_user --socket-exists -j MARK --set-mark 100
```

Then just use tc in a way it catches `mark 100`:

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 10 u32 match mark 100 ...
```

This was just my mindflow and I have no idea if this works, but give it a try. :)

Comment: The `owner` module also supports the specification of a PID: `-m owner --pid-owner <pid>`

Comment: Welcome. Although I doubt it will help resolve the question - the original poster seems to be using BSD.

Comment: Let's see about that. This lottery could go both ways; tags mention Linux and I think `tc` is more Linux oriented command.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was using BSD then switched to Linux so I could use tc.